# selenium code for date picker

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

yatra.com website for which i am not able to locate the xpath, however i have used readonly attribute, but i want the date should be selected from the datepicker. here is my code.

```
     WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BE_flight_depart_date']"));
     dateWidget.click();
     List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='calmain']"));  

     //comparing the text of cell with today's date and clicking it.
     for (WebElement cell : columns)
     {
        if (cell.getText().equals(today))
        {
           cell.click();
           break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the your problem?

Comment: i want to select particular date so for that i used following code     WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BE_flight_depart_date']"));
         dateWidget.click();
         WebElement selectdate=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='calmain']/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]"));
         selectdate.click();//28/01/2015
         selectdate.submit();    when i run this code it gives below error :---element not visible

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to switch to the datepicker window - I noticed it is a "window" object, you might have to switchtowindow before trying to select the date.

The code will look something like this -

```
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String handle : windowHandles){  
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);  
    if (driver.getAttribute(“name”).contains("data-citycode")) {
      break;  
    }  
 }
```

NOTE: I have not tested this code, try it out. you need to switch back to the main window ones the activity is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code to select a date:

```
dr.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sprite.calenderIcon[onclick*='DepartDate']"))
        .click();
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='a_2015_1_16']")).click(); // for selecting 16 jan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve date selection with following method. In the method, you need to pass string parameter date where date should follow format:

1. `YYYY-MM-DD` if day and month are of two digits
2. `YYYY-M-D` if day and month are of one digit
3. `YYYY-M-DD` if day is of two and month is of one digit
4. `YYYY-MM-D` if day is of one and month is of two digits

Examples - for 2nd Jan, 2015 pass date as `2015-1-2`, for 25th Jan, 2015 pass date as `2015-1-25`

```
public void selectYatraDate(String date) {
  date = date.replace("-", "_");
  String dateLocator = "a_" + date;

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='sprite calenderIcon']")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.id(dateLocator)).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Stack {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void clickDate() {
        String PROXY = "Give your IP address and port";

        org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY).setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.yatra.com/");
        driver.findElement(
                By.cssSelector("ul[class='travelDetails clearfix']>li[class='flL relative']>i[class='sprite calenderIcon']"))
                .click();

        boolean status = false;
        String givenDay = "31";
        List<WebElement> getCalendardays = driver
                .findElements(By
                        .xpath("//div[@id='js_mainclaendar']/div/table[@class='tableCanleder']/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class,'tdOff activeTD')]"));

        for (int i = 0; i < getCalendardays.size(); i++) {
            String sdays = getCalendardays.get(i).getText();
            if (givenDay.equals(sdays)) {
                status = true;
                getCalendardays.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (status == false) {
            Assert.fail("Not able to find the day"
                    + "("
                    + givenDay
                    + ")"
                    + "in calendar. The resason might be 1.The given day is not in calendar. 2. The given day might be disable");
        }
    }

}
```